# How to make struct immutable inside a class definition

Tags: c#, class, struct, immutability

I have a question about creating an immutable struct inside a class definition. I want to define the struct outside the class but use that same struct type in the class definition while maintaining immutability. Will the code below achieve this?

```
namespace space
{
    class Class1
    {
        public Struct {get; set;}
    }
    public Struct
    {
        public Struct(string strVar)
        {
            StructVar = strVar;
        }
        public string StructVar {get;}
    }
}
```

Also, if I have a struct within a struct like:

```
class Class1
{
    public Struct2 {get; set;}
}
public struct Struct2
{
    public Struct2(string str, InStruct inStrct)
    {
        StrVar = str;
        InStruct = inStrct;
    }
    public string StrVar {get;}
    public InStruct InStruct {get;}
}
public struct InStruct
{
    public InStruct(Array ary)
    {
        StrArray = ary
    }
    public Array StrArray {get;}
}
```

Does this also maintain immutability?

Lastly, if the size of the array in the InStruct is likely to be quite long, should I not use a struct at all and just put the array itself into the class definition instead? Am I just going struct crazy?

My concern is that because I'm doing a {set;} in the class definition that I'm breaking a rule somewhere. I would put the struct in the class definition itself but I didn't like to have to continuously call class constructors over and over to create each struct, that kind of seemed to defeat the purpose of using a struct in the first place.

Comment: `public Struct {get; set;}` is not valid code. You have to specify both the type and a name for the property.

Comment: Note that Array is not immutable, so, thought you can't assign a new Array, you can change it's elements values. Just try: `InStruct ist = new InStruct(new int[]{0,1,2}); ist.StrArray.SetValue(10,0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to give a complete answer without understanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but I'll start with a few important distinctions.

First, in C#, the struct/class distinction isn't about mutability per se. You can have a immutable class, like this one

```
public class CannotBeMutated
{
    private string someVal;
    public CannotBeMutated(string someVal)
    {
        _someVal = someVal
    }

    public string SomeVal => _someVal;
}
```

and a mutable struct, like this one

```
// This is not at all idiomatic C#, please don't use this as an example
public struct MutableStruct
{
      private string _someVal;
      public MutableStruct(string someVal)
      {
          _someVal = someVal;
      }

      public void GetVal()
      {
          return _someVal
      }

      public void Mutate(string newVal)
      {
          _someVal = newVal;
      }
}
```

Using the above struct I can do this

```
 var foo = new MutableStruct("Hello");
 foo.mutate("GoodBye");
 var bar = foo.GetVal(); // bar == "GoodBye"!
```

The difference between structs and classes is in variable passing semantics. When an object of a value type (e.g. a struct) is assigned to a variable, passed as a parameter to or returned from a method (including a property getter or setter) a copy of the object is made before it is passed to the new function context. When a object of a reference type is passed as a parameter to or returned from a method, no copy is made, because we only pass a *reference to* the object's location in memory, rather than a copy of the object.

An additional point on struct 'copying'. Imagine you have a struct with a field that is a reference type, like this

```
public struct StructWithAReferenceType
{
   public List<string> IAmAReferenceType {get; set;}
}
```

When you pass an instance of this struct into a method, a copy of the reference to the List will be copied, but the underlying data will not. So if you do

public void MessWithYourSruct(StructWithAReferenceType t)
   {
        t.IAmAReferenceType.Add("HAHA");
   }

var s = new StructWithAReferenceType { IAmAReferenceType = new List()};
   MessWithYourSruct(s);
   s.IAmAReferenceType.Count; // 1!

// or even more unsettling
   var s = new StructWithAReferenceType { IAmAReferenceType = new List()};
   var t = s; // makes a COPY of s
   s.IAmAReferenceType.Add("hi");
   t.IAmAReferenceType.Count; // 1!

Even when a struct is copied, its reference type fields still refer to the same objects in memory.

The immutable/mutable and struct/class differences are somewhat similar, insofar as they are both about where and whether you can change the contents of an object in your program, but they are still very distinct.

Now on to your question. In your second example, Class1 is not immutable, as you can mutate the value of Struct2 like this

```
var foo = new Class1();
foo.Struct2 = new Struct2("a", 1);
foo.Struct2 // returns a copy of Struct2("a", 1);
foo.Struct2 = new Struct2("b", 2);
foo.Struct2 // returns a copy of Struct2("b", 2);
```

Struct2 is immutable, as there is no way for calling code to change the values of `StrVar` or `InVar` once. InStruct is similarly immutable. However, Array is *not* immutable. So InStruct is an immutable container for a mutable value. Similar to if you had a `ImmutableList<List<string>>`. While you can guarantee calling code does not change the value of InStruct.StrArray to a different array, you can do nothing about calling code changing the value of the objects *in* the Array.

Finally, some generic advice related to your example.

First, mutable structs, or structs with mutable fields, are bad. The examples above should point to why structs with mutable fields are bad. And Eric Lippert himself has a great example of how terrible mutable structs can be on his blog [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/)

Second, for most developers working in C# there's almost never a reason to create a user defined value type (i.e. a struct). Objects of value types are stored on the stack, which makes memory access to them very fast. Objects of reference types are stored on the heap, and so are slower to access. But in the *huge* majority of C# programs, that distinction is going to be dwarfed by the time cost of disk I/O, network I/O, reflection in serialization code, or even initialization and manipulation of collections. For ordinary developers who aren't writing performance-critical standard libraries, there's almost no reason to think about the performance implications of the difference. Heck, developers in Java, Python, Ruby, Javascript and many other languages get by in languages totally without user-defined value types. Generally, the added cognitive overhead they introduce for developers is almost never worth any benefit you might see. Also, remember that large structs must be copied whenever they are passed or assigned to a variable, and can actually be a performance problem.

TL;DR you probably shouldn't use structs in your code, and they don't really have anything to do with immutability.